# Git - Commit changes to another one's submodule

Tags: git

I have a git repo with submodule which belongs to someone else. Now I want to make changes to it like adding and modifying.

I think about forking the project, then I will use that as a new submodule instead. Is there anyway I can avoid this by just simply commit new file to the submodule and track it with my current repo ?

Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the repo that you have as a submodule, then you cannot make changes to it. You must have a fork and add that as a submodule. And once you make your changes, push those to submodule so that anyone cloning your repo can see those changes.

Comment: thanks for helping me clarify. I also think this is the only way :)

Answer (score 0):

A submodule is basically a repository within a repository. If you go into the directory where the submodule is located, you can use it like any git repo: `add`, `commit`, check the logs, etc. It is isolated from the other repository.

However, when the submodule changes, the parent repository shows that there is a *single* changed *directory* that must be added and committed to the parent repository.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, you can add and commit in submodule repo and track it with the parent. The file still doesn't seem to be show on my repo, so I can't pull it from another place :)